# How to exit a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

currently I am doing my assignment. The requirement is to test the format of Student ID. I wonder why is my while loop is not working properly..
My validation check is as below:

```
def isValidStudentIDFormat(stid):

# studentID must have a length of 9
if(len(stid) != 9):
    # return the invalid reason
    return "Length of Student ID is not 9"

# studentID must starts with a letter S
if(stid[0] != 'S'):
    # return the invalid reason
    return "First letter is not S"

# studentID must contains 7 numbers between the two letters
for i in range(1,8):
    # anything smaller than 0 or bigger than 9 would not be valid.
    # so does a character, will also be invalid
    if((stid[i] < '0') or (stid[i] > '9')):
        # return the invalid reason
        return "Not a number between letters"

if((stid[8] < 'A') or (stid[8] > 'Z')):
    # return the invalid reason
    return "Last letter not a characer"

# return True if the format is right
return True
```

My function to insert a student record is below:

```
def insert_student_record():
#printing the message to ask user to insert a new student into the memory
print("Insert a new student \n")
fn = input("Enter first name: ")

#check if user entered space
#strip() returns a copy of the string based on the string argument passed
while not fn.strip():      
    print("Empty input, please enter again")
    fn = input("Enter first name: ")  

ln = input("Enter last name: ")
while not ln.strip():      
    print("Empty input, please enter again")
    ln = input("Enter last name: ")   

stid = input("Enter student id: ")
while not stid.strip():      
    print("Empty input, please enter again")
    stid = input("Enter student id: ") 

result = isValidStudentIDFormat(stid) 
while (result != True):
    print("Invalid student id format. Please check and enter again.")
    stid = input("Enter student id: ")
    result == True

#append the student details to each list
#append first name
fName.append(fn)

#append last name
lName.append(ln)

#append student id
sid.append(stid)

#to check if the new student is in the lists
if stid in sid:
    if fn in fName:
        if ln in lName:
            #then print message to tell user the student record is inserted
            print("A new student record is inserted.")
```

However, I'm getting an infinite loop even if I key in the correct format for student ID. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Indentation dictates flow inside python - please format your code exactly as you have it in your IDE.

Comment: Is your code indented exactly as it is above? If not please edit the above to look like it is on your editor. Unlike other languages, indentation is important in python and affects how the code is interpreted

Comment: Generally, returning a string and a boolean just causes confusion. You should learn about `try` and `raise` if you want exception messages

Comment: Hi guys, my indentation is correct, I don't know what happened when I copy over. I will change it.

Comment: Hi guys I do not know how to make the indentation correct.. But you guys can assume my indentation is correct.. haha

Answer (score 3):

You compare `result == True` when you should assign. Still, you don't check the new student id for validity, which could be done this way:

```
while (result != True):
    print("Invalid student id format. Please check and enter again.")
    stid = input("Enter student id: ")
    result = isValidStudentIDFormat(stid)
```

Answer (score 0):

?

```
def validateStudentIDFormat(stid):
    if len(stid) != 9:
        raise RuntimeError("Length of Student ID is not 9")

    if stid[0] != 'S':
        raise RuntimeError("First letter is not S")

    for char in stid[1:-1]:
        if char.isnumeric(): 
            raise RuntimeError("Not a number between letters")

    if not stid[-1].isalpha():
        raise RuntimeError("Last letter not a characer")
```

....

```
while True:
    stid = input("Enter student id: ")
    try:
        validateStudentIDFormat(stid) 
    except RuntimeError as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("Invalid student id format. Please check and enter again.")
    else:
        break
```